# Mapbox add interactivity to polygon in FillLayer

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-ios

I have a FillLayer with polygons generated from a local geojson file. I want to add interactivity to these polygons but am not sure how to do it with the iOS SDK. I found an example that is able to do something similar to what I need to do but in the Mapbox-GL-JS environment:

```
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/
```

You can add a gesture recognizer to the map in the iOS SDK like this

```
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.mapClickedFunction)))
```

but you can't seem to add a gesture recognizer to the layer or the polygons inside the layer. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tap point received from the gesture recognizer to query the map for rendered features at the given point within the layer specified.

```
    @objc public func findFeatures(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)

        mapView.mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(
            with: tapPoint,
            options: RenderedQueryOptions(layerIds: ["US-states"], filter: nil)) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let queriedfeatures):
                if let firstFeature = queriedfeatures.first?.feature.properties,
                   case let .string(stateName) = firstFeature["STATE_NAME"] {
                    self?.showAlert(with: "You selected \(stateName)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.showAlert(with: "An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a chunk of code from MapBox examples. The logic is to put the gesture recognizer on the map view. When a tap gesture is received you get the location where user tapped as `CGPoint` coordinate inside the map view. Then you send it to `MapboxMap` in order to get a list o features that contain that point.

I recommend you to take a look at the official Mapbox repository that contains a lot of ways of doing things:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/tree/main/Apps/Examples

Have a nice day!